# Notification for votes after daily reputation cap?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, daily-reputation-limit

Is there a way to know which posts I wrote get votes after I reach the daily reputation limit?

Before the dalily reputation limit we can see voting activity in the recent achievements dropdown :

[image: recent achievements dropdown]

But I noticed more voting activity after the reputation cap and didn't get notified. Is there a way to see/get notified for those votes?

---

**Edit :**

As stated in the comments, a notification for votes after the reputation cap is reached would be great so I am tagging this question as a feature request.

Comment: First world problem....

Comment: I don't know the opinion of people who are very often long past that cap but personally I'd really like to still get the notifications even if they're not linked to reputation changes.

Comment: Make a feature request - I'd also love a +0 notification.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum done!

Comment: If SO wanted to say 'Good Morning' to Jon Skeet every day, there are easier ways to do so.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I don't know of any way of being notified for those votes, but you can go into the reputation tab in your user profile and you'll see votes there with no reputation change associated with them.

Comment: Don't trust this guy - I doubt he has ever hit the rep cap in his life.

Comment: Plus, that hat looks *way* to perfect. Did the dev team test them all on his gravatar?